# Can i control volume on Raspberry Pi from Java ? (3.5 Jack)

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm using Raspbian.
I found PI4J library to control GPIO's. Now i want to control the sound (make it squeak) on 3.5 Jack. Is there a library or commands for this ?

Answer (score 0):

What are you running? (Raspbian, XBMC, Arch...)

I don't know of any libraries that could do this for you, but you can always resort to the following... assuming you're using Rasbian.

Use Java to make the following system calls with 'exec':

```
amixer -c 0 set PCM 2dB+   // Volume up.
amixer -c 0 set PCM 2dB-   // Volume down.
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:  As for your new question, you can try the following:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```

Comment: I'm using raspbian.Sorry for my bad expressed thought. I mean I want to make it squeak.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the term 'squeak'.  Can you define it for me in relation to computer terms?

Comment: I edited my answer for your new question.  If this helped, please select it.